# Wait for http response in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am using angularJS, and i am trying to get a result from the back-end using a service like this:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', function ($http, $window, $rootScope) {

return {
    GetTypeName(typeID, callback) {
        $http.get(backend_url + 'type/getById/' + typeID)
            .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {

                if (status === 200) {
                    callback(true, response);
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                callback(false);
            });
    }
}   }]);
```

And i am calling that service from this controller:

```
getFormationsType = function(){
 for (i = 0; i!= array.length;i++){
     myService.GetTypeName(typeID, function (result, data) {
         if(result){
             console.log(data.name);
             // do something with data.name here, and also need it outside of this func
         } else{
             console.log("error");
         }
     });
 }}
```

The problem is that, when the function executes the service, it doesn´t wait for the result, and jumps out of the getFormationsType() func, and does other stuff that comes next, before it give back the result, and i need that result right away.
So basically i need help to understand how can i make the service wait for the result before jumping out.

Thank you.

Comment: Making it “wait” in a for loop would be challenging indeed. What are you trying to “wait” for, and how do you want to use it?

Comment: Check out [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Comment: Might be you are calling two events at a same time. So that was the reason you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick answers, i need to get from the backend a string given an ID, and i have multiples ID's, stored in an array, and i need to run a for loop, to get every single id, and call the service using all id's to get all the diferent strings.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs only works with promise implemented by `$q` , so you can not use es6's promise and  async/await. you can achieve your aim with `$q` like this:

first change you service to return a promise instance:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($http, $window, $rootScope, $q) {

    return {
        getTypeName(typeID) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(backend_url + 'type/getById/' + typeID)
                .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {

                    if (status === 200) {
                        deferred.resolve({ success: true, data: response });
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve({ success: false });
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve({ success: false });
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

and then, in your controller, call your service recursively like this:

```
angular.controller('myController', ['myService', function (myService) {
    var array = [/* init your type id array here. */];
    var index = 0;
    function getFormationsType () {
        myService.getTypeName(this.array[this.index])
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                if (this.index < this.array.length) {
                    this.index += 1;
                    getFormationsType();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}]);
```